# how to create custom elementor widget and embed to shortcode?

Tags: widget, elementor, custom-widgets

I want to ask something regarding elementor. Actually I created some widgets but i want to add these widgets in custom theme template as a shortcode. and when developer edit this page that page already embed elemtor-widget to shorcode then this will editable

Answer (score 0):

Use
[AnyWhere Elementor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/anywhere-elementor/) plugin by the help of this plugin you can use Elementor template as shortcode

Comment: Thankyou so much for your time but I found my solution

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35767026)